# ArcGIS Portal not working with LDAP users

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal, security, arcgis-enterprise

I have set user identity store of ArcGIS Portal administration page like following.

```
{
  "type": "LDAP",
  "properties": {
    "userPassword": "secret",
    "isPasswordEncrypted": "false",
    "user": "uid=gisuser,ou=systemusers",
    "userFullnameAttribute": "displayName",
    "userGivenNameAttribute": "givenName",
    "userSurnameAttribute": "cn",
    "ldapURLForUsers": "ldaps://10.0.0.5:636/ou=users,ou=ags,dc=example,dc=com",
    "userEmailAttribute": "mail",
    "usernameAttribute": "uid",
    "caseSensitive": "false",
    "userSearchAttribute": "cn", 
  }
}
```

After save the configurations, I tried to add members based on existing enterprise users in Portal. But no users found. The search result is empty whatever I searched.

Why does this happen?

Comment: is port 636 blocked on your portal server? If using a global catalog on windows then try https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/configuring-the-domain-controller-used-by-portal-for-arcgis.htm

Comment: I have installed [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adexplorer](active directory explorer)  and it works. I tried LDAP with port 389 explorer tool it works and I set the same configuration in json but does not work.

Comment: @Mapperzwhat do you mean with `global catalog on windows`

Comment: Depends on your IT setup - https://theitbros.com/global-catalog-active-directory/